# How to keep rows based on percentile score of a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1:

```
county         state       score1 score2  FIPS
Abbeville South Carolina     3      0 45001
Acadia    Louisiana          11     1 22001
Accomack  Virginia           6      0 51001
3Ada      Idaho              151    3 16001
Adair     Iowa               1      0 19001
Adair     Missouri           2      0 29001
```

I would like to keep rows if they are in the top 40 percentile based on `score1` values. How can I do this? Is there a way to create a new column of A and B values to indicate if it is in the top 40% or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the 60th percentile--the cutoff for the top 40%--of score1 using `quantile(df1$score1, 0.6)`.

For what you describe as a new column of A and B values, I'm assuming you want A if it's in the top 40% and B if it's not?  To get that, you can do

```r
df1$top40perc[df1$score1 >= quantile(df1$score1, 0.6)] <- "A"
df1$top40perc[df1$score1 < quantile(df1$score1, 0.6)] <- "B"
```

(There's probably a way to combine those, but I'm not sure of it off the top of my head.)

Comment: `df1$top40perc <- ifelse(df1$score1 >= quantile(df1$score1, 0.6), "A", "B")` is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

This calculates the 60th percentile based on score1 and filters out rows where score1 is not > the 60th percentile:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(percentile_60 = quantile(score1, probs = c(.6)),
         flag = score1 > percentile_60) %>% 
  filter(flag == TRUE)
```

Comment: The **top 40%** based on score1 means greater than 0.6 quantile, not 0.4.